# Mongoose: call object method in query select

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema, and added a method to it:

```
// define a schema
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.slug = function () {
  return  type: this.type + '-' + this.name;
}
```

Used like so:

```
var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'Bill });

dog.slug(); // 'dog-Bill'
```

I would like to query on animal and get method result in select:

```
Animal.find({type: 'dog'}).select('type name slug'); // [{type: 'dog', name: 'Bill', slug: 'dog-Bill'}]
```

Any chance I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won’t work with a [`method`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods), but it will with a [`virtual`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) property.

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

animalSchema.virtual('slug').get(function () {
  return this.type + '-' + this.name;
});
```

In order to have the virtual properties when the model is [converted to JSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON), you need to pass `virtuals: true`.

```
animal.toJSON({ virtuals: true })
```

You can configure your schema to always resolve virtuals.

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});
```

Or

```
animalSchema.set('toJSON', {
   virtuals: true
});
```